# Sending e-mail with a Python script deployed on a Linode server using the SMTP library

Tags: python, email, smtp, linode

So I've created a script which sends an update e-mail when the script is finished running. It all works fine locally. But when deployed and ran on a Linode server it doesn't work anymore. Here is the code:

```
def email(products, new_products, updated_products):
    #print(products, new_products, updated_products)
    message = EmailMessage()
    message.set_content("Products scraped: {}, New products: {}, Updated products: {}".format(products, new_products, updated_products))
    message['FROM'] = "e-mail"
    message['TO'] = ["e-mail"]
    message['SUBJECT'] = "Update"
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    #set up SMTP server
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.starttls(context=context)
        smtp.login(message['FROM'], "password")
        smtp.send_message(message)
        smtp.quit()
```

The error occurs on the line: with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp. I've tried different ports, but it all results in this error: TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out. Has anyone had this problem? Or does anyone have another good way to send an e-mail from a server? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Linode block outgoing mail by default to prevent spam.

https://www.linode.com/community/questions/19082/i-just-created-my-first-linode-and-i-cant-send-emails-why-mailing-ports-25-465-a

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! I will open a support ticket with Linode.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling less secure apps for the email id you want to send emails from